# Wohin schreibt man den Namenszusatz in Formularen / Urkunden bei "Nachname, Vorname"

Tags: person-names, rules

Zunächst einmal zur Einordnung: Unter Namenszusätzen verstehe ich hier Wörter, wie "de, De, Mc, von, van" etc., die nicht mit dem Familiennamen verschmolzen sind.

> Also Namen wie: Vincent van Gogh, Max von Mustermann, Ursula von der Leyen, Sky du Mont

> Aber nicht: Carson McCullers, Marcus DuMont

Für die alphabetische Sortierung ist nach DIN 5007 der Fall klar. Der Namenszusatz wird hinter den Vornamen gestellt und nur der Familienname zur Sortierung herangezogen.

> Also z.B.: Mustermann, Max von

Wie schreibt man allerdings solche Namen in Formularen, die oft die Form "Nachname, Vorname" haben. Greift hier ebenfalls DIN 5007 oder gibt es da eine andere DIN oder offizielle Vorgaben? Gibt es eine Unterscheidung dazu für offizielle Dokumente, die hin und wieder auch den Namen als "Nachname, Vorname" ausgeben.

Schreibt man also ebenfalls

> Mustermann, Max von

oder

> von Mustermann, Max

oder

> Von Mustermann, Max

Zusatz, damit es nicht so einfach ist: Ich suche nach belastbaren Quellen für die Handhabe in Deutschland. Nicht nach "gefällt mir so besser" ;)

**EDIT:**

Um die Frage vielleicht etwas klarer zu machen und ein Praxisbeispiel zu geben:

Es existieren drei Datenbankfelder "Vorname", "Nachname" und "Namenszusatz" gefüllt mit "Max", "Mustermann" und "von".

Ausgegeben werden soll etwas in der Form von

> Hiermit bescheinigen wir "Nachname", "Vorname", geboren am XX.XX.XXXX in ...

Die Frage ist hier, wo das "von" an dieser Stelle hinkommt.

Die andere Frage ist, was man macht, wenn die Überschrift

> Nachname, Vorname

lautet. Was wird dann ausgegeben und sollte der Namenszusatz in diesem Fall an erster Stelle stehen wird dieser dann groß- oder kleingeschrieben?

Comment: Die Internationalisierung würde solche Regelungen übrigens auch immer komplexer oder wahlweise unzureichend machen. Die internationale Vielfalt an Regeln rund um Personennamen ist absolut atemberaubend: https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: Spanier mit mütter- und väterlichen Nachnamen, them 'murricans mit middle initial und durchzählen, und was es sonst noch so alles gibt. Nicht umsonst gibt's Ausweis- oder Sozialversicherungsnummern :-)

Answer (score 4):

Der Zusatz ist ein untrennbarer Teil des Nachnamens.

Beispiel: [Alexander Van der Bellen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Van_der_Bellen), amtierender österreichsicher Bundespräsident:

- Van der Bellen, Alexander

oder [Lius de Broglie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Broglie), französischer Physiker

- de Broglie, Luis

Bei Van der Bellen ist das nicht so offensichtlich, weil man das *»Van«* in seinem Namen ohnehin großschreibt, aber bei de Broglie zeigt sich auch, dass der Zusatz auch dann kleingeschrieben wird, wenn der Nachname ohne Vorname verwendet wird:

aus dem oben verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel:

> Ende des Jahres 1923 erschienen **de Broglies** erste Abhandlungen zur Wellenmechanik.

Aus [Wikipedia: Vincent van Gogh](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_van_Gogh):

> Einige Autoren vertreten die Meinung, dass **van Gogh** sich als ungeliebten Ersatz für den Erstgeborenen empfunden und dadurch seelischen Schaden genommen habe.

[Ursula von der Leyen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_von_der_Leyen):

> Im Jahr 2020 führte das Time Magazine **von der Leyen** in der Liste der 100 einflussreichsten Personen.

Anhand dieser Beispiele wird deutlich, dass die Zusätze untrennbare Bestandteile des Nachnamens sind. Niemand spricht vom *Herrn Bellen* oder von der *Frau Leyen,* sondern vom *Herrn Van der Bellen* und von der  *Frau von der Leyen.* Daher ist immer dann, wenn der Nachname anzugeben ist, der ganze Nachname (inklusive der Zusätze) anzugeben.

Comment: Deine Beispiele beziehen sich auf den normalen Sprachgebrauch und da bin ich auch bei dir. Auch wenn man diskutieren kann, warum wir von Goethe und nicht von von Goethe sprechen ;) . Aber wie schon geschrieben wird in DIN 5007 der Zusatz nicht als Teil des Nachnamens gesehen. Es ist da "Broglie, Luis de". Lustigerweise hat Van der Bellen durch das große "V" in Lexika wohl eine Sonderstellung und würde dort unter V einsortiert werden. Ich habe das Gefühl die Antwort geht leider an der Frage vorbei. Außerdem, würde man wenn dem so ist "de Broglie, Luis" oder "De Broglie, Luis" schreiben?

Comment: Es geht mir wie gesagt nicht um Fließtext, sondern um die Felder "Nachname, Vorname" in Formularen, etc.

Comment: @mtwde Entscheidend ist für solche Formulare keine DIN-Norm, sondern was laut Geburten- bzw. Personenstandsregister der Nachname ist. Da ein "von" Teil des Namens ist, offensichtlich aber nicht Teil der Vornamen sein kann, würde ich sagen, dass es stets Teil des Familiennamens sein muss. Ich finde aber auf die Schnelle keine gesetzliche Regelung dazu.

Comment: Mit der Untrennbarkeit ist das so eine Sache. Während zum Beispiel das kleingeschriebene "van" bei van Gogh und van Eyck praktisch immer ausgeschrieben wird, fehlt es bei Beethoven in der Regel.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Namenszusatz ist Teil des Familiennamens – er wird an Kinder weitergegeben und bei der förmlichen Anrede benutzt. Wenn dieser Zusatz gesondert gespeichert ist und in das Schema *Nachname, Vorname* eingeordnet werden muss, gehört er deshalb grundsätzlich vor den Nachnamen und nicht hinter den Vornamen:

> *von Mustermann, Max*.

Die Groß- und Kleinschreibung des Zusatzes richtet sich nach der für den jeweiligen Zweck verbindlichen (i.d.R. der amtlichen) Schreibweise (siehe [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/namen#K134)). Das heißt: in einem Formular oder auch innerhalb eines Satzes wird ein Zusatz dann kleingeschrieben, wenn das der offiziellen Schreibweise entspricht (wie i.d.R. beim deutschen *von*). Dazu heißt es im amtlichen Regelwerk:

> [**§ 60 Abs. 1**](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6195#par60-1) Präpositionen wie von, van, de, ten, zu(r) in Personennamen schreibt man im Satzinnern auch dann klein, wenn ihnen kein Vorname vorausgeht, zum Beispiel: Der Autor dieses Buches heißt *von Ossietzky*.

Es gibt jedoch auch Zusätze wie das französische *Le*, die standardmäßig großgeschrieben werden, sowie Eigennamen (z.B. nach Auswanderung in die USA), in denen sonst kleingeschriebene Zusätze großgeschrieben werden:

> - (Regel:) Hiermit bescheinigen wir *von Mustermann, Max*, geboren …
> - (Regel:) Hiermit bescheinigen wir [*Le Blanc, Thomas*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Le_Blanc), geboren …
> - (Ausnahme:) Hiermit bescheinigen wir [*Von Dohlen, Lenny*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenny_Von_Dohlen), geboren …

Am Satzanfang werden jedoch alle Namenszusätze nach der allgemeinen Regel wie andere Wörter auch großgeschrieben (*von* und *van* sollten dann nicht abgekürzt werden, um Verwechslungen mit dem Vornamen zu vermeiden):

> - *Von Mustermann, Max* bescheinigen wir hiermit …
> - (nicht:) <s>*V. Mustermann, Max*</s> bescheinigen wir hiermit …

---

Exkurs: Die Nennung in [alphabetischen Namens**listen**](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Alphabetische-Namenslisten) richtet sich nach ganz anderen Regeln. Hier bleiben kleingeschriebene Namenszusätze bei der Sortierung unberücksichtigt und werden der Übersichtlichkeit halber deshalb oft hinter den Vornamen gestellt. Tatsächlich gilt dies jedoch wiederum nicht für großgeschriebene Namenszusätze (Duden, siehe Link):

> Namenszusätze wie de, van oder von bleiben bei der Alphabetisierung grundsätzlich unberücksichtigt, also beispielsweise Nolde – Nolden – van Norden oder Maisel – Maiser – de Maizière, es sei denn, sie werden großgeschrieben, z. B. Vanbrugh – Van Buren – Vance.

In einer **alphabetischen Liste** stünde daher abweichend von den o.g. Regeln:

> nur in alphabetischen Listen:
>
> - Beethoven, Ludwig van
> - Le Blanc, Thomas
> - Mustermann, Max von
> - Van der Bellen, Alexander
> - Von Dohlen, Lenny

Großgeschriebene Namenszusätze sollten daher wohl am besten gar nicht erst gesondert gespeichert werden, da sie stets als Einheit behandelt werden.

Answer (score -1):

Hier ist es relativ klar beantwortet. Seit 1919 ist jeglicher Namenszusatz (also auch Graf/Gräfin etc.) Bestandteil des Nachnamens. Also: von Mustermann, Max

https://www.protokoll-inland.de/Webs/PI/DE/anschriften-anreden/familiennamen-mit-adelsbezeichnungen/familiennamen-ehemalige-adelsbezeichnungen-node.html