# Namensschreibweise

Tags: grammatical-case, word-order

In Deutschland gibt es ja die Vorwärtsschreibweise eines Namens (also mit Vorname/Nachname) und die Rückwärtsschreibweise (also mit Nachname, Vorname).

Wenn die Vorwärtsschreibweise lautet "**Dr. Johann Graf von der Vogelweide**", wie wäre dann die Rückwärtsschreibweise?

**Dr. von der Vogelweide, Johann Graf**?

Speziell beim "**Graf**" als Namenszusatz bin ich mir hier nicht sicher und bitte um Hilfe.

Comment: Nicht exakt ein Duplikat, aber interessant sein dürfte [Wohin schreibt man den Namenszusatz in Formularen / Urkunden bei "Nachname, Vorname"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65698/wohin-schreibt-man-den-namenszusatz-in-formularen-urkunden-bei-nachname-vorn).

Comment: "Graf" ist in Detschland kein Namenszusatz, sondern Teil des Nachnamens. Der Doktortitel ist ein Namenszusatz und kann u.U. mit dem Nachnamen aufgeführt werden: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namenszusatz#Deutschland_2 Ergo: Dr. Graf von der Vogelweide, Johann

Comment: @Roland: Stimmt, aber das ist eine Antwort, kein Kommentar zur Frage.

Answer (score 3):

Dazu gibt es keine eindeutige Antwort:

Das Namensrecht hat mit der Abschaffung der Adelstitel den Titel zum Nachnamensbestandteil gemacht. Damit würde der Familienname aus deinem Beispliel

> Graf von der Vogelweide

lauten.

In sortierten Listen (Telefonbüchern, Adressbüchern,..., aber auch z.B. in Literaturverzeichnissen, die nach Verfassern sortiert sind) wird allerdings oft die Konvention gewählt, dass der Nachname unter Weglassung der Titel einsortiert wird (das scheint deine Frage zu sein). Dazu muss man nicht unbedingt die Reihenfolge der Namensbestandteile ändern:

```
von Goethe, Johann Wolfgang 
Mustermann, Manuela
Vater, Johann
Victor, Hans
Graf von der Vogelweide, Johann, Dr.
Vulpius, Martin
```

Will man unbedingt, dass im Beispiel "alles mit 'V' anfängt", kann man den Hausnamen vorziehen und den Adelstitel nach z.B. dem Vornamen und akademischen Grad mit Komma anhängen - wissend, dass man dabei eigentlich einen falschen Familiennamen erzeugt - deshalb ist das nicht empfehlenswert. Ich finde die vorherige Methode eleganter.

Comment: +1.In meiner Erfahrung ist aber die häufiger vorkommende Variante, die die Namen mit Adelstiteln 'zerschneidet': Goethe, Johann Wolfgang von. Schön sind auch Eingabemasken im www, die keine nachnamen mit Leerzeichen erlauben

Comment: @planetmaker - Ich *sah* die früher auch häufiger. In letzter Zeit nehme ich häufiger "meine" wahr.

Comment: Ja, das ändert sich in die Richtung, dem stimme ich zu. Die Mehrheit ist es aber nach meiner Erfahrung noch nicht. Aber das ist subjektiv

Comment: Siehe dazu auch: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Auch andre Länder haben ähnliche Probleme mit mehrteiligen Nachnamen (auch wenn's dort keine ehemaligen Adelstitel sind): So habe ich irgendwann mal gelernt, dass "van Gogh" in einem niederländischen Telefonbuch unter "G" zu suchen wäre, in einem belgisch-flämischen aber unter "V".

Comment: das 'van' ist doch das gleiche wie das 'von'... auch ein ehemaliger Adelstitel. Ebenso das französische 'de' (oder auch du bzw. d')

Comment: @planetmaker Nö, isset nich. Die niederländischen Formen von "van xxx" und "de yyy" haben nichts mit Adelstiteln zu tun. "van Gogh" ist einfach der Vincent aus Gogh, und "Mefrouw Jeanette de Meulnare" ist einfach Frau Jeanette die Müllerin.